# $this->input->xss_clean($data) giving fatal error with codeigniter

Tags: sql-injection, codeigniter-2

I am getting an error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::xss_clean()
following is the setting and code that I've written.

```
config.php
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

$data=array();
$data['fname']=$this->input->post("fname");
$this->input->xss_clean($data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xss_clean() method does not exist in input, but in **security**.

```
$data = array();
$data['fname'] = $this->input->post("fname");
$this->security->xss_clean($data);
```